# Preimage of compact compact set is compact for a bijective map.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(M,d)$ and $(N,d)$ be metric spaces with $f :(M, d) \rightarrow (N, d)$ a bijective function such that $f(A)$ is open in $N$, for all $A\subseteq M$. Show that if $B$ is compact in $N$, then $f^{-1}(B)$ is compact in $M$.
I know I must show that every open cover  $A_{\lambda}$ where  $\lambda \in G$ for some family $G$ covering $f^{-1}(B)$ admits a finite subcover.
Can anyone help me prove it?

Comment: What do you mean by "open to all $A\subseteq M$"?

Comment: **f(a) is open**

Comment: And a is a set or an element of the set? Usually we restrict sets to capital letters.

Comment: **I believe that this group**

Comment: I don't think group properties are necessary or stated here, I think you mean that $f(A)$ is open in $N$ for $A \subseteq M$, implying that $f$ is an open map.

Comment: **I think so, just do not understand what is open map. Sorry I'm Brazilian, maybe change the words a bit ...**

Comment: It's okay, I submitted an edit of the problem statement to make it more readable. Basically you are saying that if you have a compact subset, $B$, of the image, $Y$, you can take the preimage of that subset (or take the inverse) under the map $f:X\rightarrow Y$ and get a compact subset in $X$. Also, I assume you are working with metric spaces (since this is tagged real-analysis). Does this make sense to you?

Comment: **Yes that is exactly, vc understood exactly what I mean. Thank you.**

Comment: $f$ is open so $f^{-1}$ is continuous so the image by $f^{-1}$ of a compact set is a compact set.

Comment: Just: why the bold characters in all your comments?

Answer (score 1):

Viviane I am not sure what results you have used, but the main theorem on compactness is that the image of a compact set is compact. Since $f$ is open, $f^{-1}$ is continuous because the preimage of an open set under $f^{-1}$, which is $f$, is open in $X$. I.e. for $A$ an open subset of $X$, $(f^{-1})^{-1})(A) = f(A)$ is open, so $f^{-1}$ is continuous. Then, you have that the continuous image of a compact set is compact. If you do not have this theorem I will leave it to you to prove, it is relatively straightforward using the definition you know.

Comment: **ok, I'll try to develop and then post here. Thank you**